# functional is not a member of play.api.lib--Convert Scala Map to JSON using play-json

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

Unable to convert Scala Map to JSON using play json.

Code:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val scalaMap = Map("Abc" -> "Def") 
Json.stringify(Json.toJson(scalaMap))
```

The error I'm getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/api/libs/functional/ContravariantFunctor
... 50 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 50 more
```

Library  used

```
ibraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.7"
```

Comment: In ScalaFiddle this works: see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uYvJ7fq/1. The dependency there is https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-derived-codecs which includes play-json.

Comment: this works without errors on my machine, maybe your dependencies somehow got misplaced/deleted or otherwise broken?